# ssh keys ssh-agent bash and ssh-add

Tags: linux, ssh

I am new to ssh keys. Can anyone explain how the `ssh-agent bash` and `ssh-add` works?

I need to understand its internals in future.

Comment: Have you tried the top Google hit for any of these terms?

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't get any useful information. My bad

Answer (score 54, accepted):

An ***agent*** is a program that keeps your keys in memory so that you only need to unlock them *once*, instead of every time. *ssh-agent* does this for SSH keys.

The usual methods for **starting *ssh-agent*** are:

- `` eval `ssh-agent` `` – this runs the agent in background, and sets the apropriate environment variables for the *current* shell instance.

  (*ssh-agent*, when started with no arguments, outputs commands to be interpreted by your shell.)
- `exec ssh-agent bash` – starts a *new* instance of the `bash` shell, replacing the current one.

  (With one or more arguments, *ssh-agent* doesn't output anything, but starts the specified command: in this case, the `bash` shell, but technically it could be anything.)

  The second method is sometimes preferred, since it automatically kills ssh-agent when you close the terminal window. (When starting it with `eval`, the agent would remain running, but inaccessible.)

However, this only starts an empty agent. To actually make it useful, you need to use ***ssh-add***, which unlocks your keys (usually `~/.ssh/id_*`) and loads them into the agent, making them accessible to *ssh* or *sftp* connections.

Comment: Is there a way to start ssh-agent across multiple bash sessions, once?

Answer (score 12):

Additionally, you may want to add some keys at session start.

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file, and add :

```
ssh-add &>/dev/null || eval `ssh-agent` &>/dev/null  # start ssh-agent if not present
[ $? -eq 0 ] && {                                     # ssh-agent has started
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private.key1 &>/dev/null        # Load key 1
ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private.key2 &>/dev/null        # Load key 2
}
```

Check your keys with `ssh-add -l`

You can stop the current ssh-agent session with `ssh-agent -k`

Something to know about ssh-agent and .bashrc is don't load too many keys. The default number of tries for ssh daemon is limited to 6. This can been modified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the `MaxAuthTries` value.

Comment: What about the private key password when launching `ssh-add` with "&" ? Are you assuming the private key files are unprotected ?

Comment: The code above asks for the passphrase twice, once when checking if ssh-agent is available and again once loading the private key.

Comment: @Luciano just provide passphrase once and you will no longer be prompted again for any connection with this key afterwards.